# How to get Apples Human Interface Guidelines as pdf (latest version 2015)?

Tags: macos, pdf, books

I have been trying to download Apple HIG in PDF, only thing I found was [Apple HIG documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) which just gives me an ePub file for iBooks.

Things I've (unsuccessfully) tried:

- share/export from iBook as PDF (no luck)
- looked in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`
  (no PDF)
- open ePub in iBooks Author (can't open)

So how can I either get the latest HIG as a PDF or convert the ePub into PDF?

Comment: You could try converting it to another format with [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) freeware book format converter & librarian.

Answer (score 1):

iBooks has changed the download location to the "Desktop" for I don't know which reason. I found the `iOS Human interface.epub` file and loaded it with the iBooks Author app.

There I went "File" - "New from ePub file..." . After the app loaded the file I went for "File" and "Export" and finally as PDF.

I also tried downloading the .epub file onto iBooks on my iPad. There is no export option available and the mailing open only mails the link from the iTunes store and NOT the .epub file itself. Hopefully this helps someone...

Found the solution by accident , since I didn't expect the .epub file to be on my desktop...